# lecture notes about the relation between algebraic topology, topological quantum field theory, condensed matter physics

Tags: condensed-matter, topology, topological-field-theory

I am an undergraduate student and I am very interested in topology with its application in physics. So last year I've read some books about this field, mainly about topological soliton, some introductory text about topological quantum field theory and some topology with its application in condensed matter physics. During the process of my self-learning, here are some of my questions.

First I would like to search for information myself hoping to answer the question, however, it turned out to be failed. So now I post the questions on PSE, hoping somebody would answer for me.

Now, my questions are listed below:

1. if it is possible to construct topological soliton theory into the framework of topological quantum field theory? By the word "construct", I mean to express the whole topological soliton theory in TQFT's words and therefore we can naturally understand how homotopy theory play its role in this aspect
2. Is learning category theory a necessary thing to do in the process of learning TQFT?
3. what is HQFT(homotopical quantum field theory) and what's the relationship between HQFT and TQFT? Is there any real example of HQFT?
4. Can the topological method that applied in condensed matter(topological phase transition; topological order) associated with TQFT.if not, what's the relationship between these two aspects?
5. Are there any good reference for physics and topology(not just algebraic topology, differential topology and geometric topology and so on)

Comment: Please narrow the focus of your post. You’ve asked eight different questions and a post here is supposed to ask only one.

Comment: oh,sorry about the 8 question.I thought all these questions are related to each other that's why I post out all of then.So if you could excuse me, I would be really grateful. And some how I don't know how to give reply to other's comment,so I will just answer other's comment by make a comment myself